# how to change the variable use Xposed

Tags: xposed, xposed-framework

```
byte[] buffer = new buffer[1024];
io.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

Now I hook the method io.read(), is there a way to change the buffer variable.
The buffer length is 1024, I want Xposed to achieve,

```
byte[] newbuffer = new byte[4096];
buffer = newbuffer;
```

Comment: What you want will not work. The only way would be to replace the method the code `io.read(...)` is called from: replace the whole method with a modified one.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably register a beforeHookedMethod on the io.read to retrieve the read's parameters. You can access these via [param.args](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.java#L80), just create your new buffer and replace it in the arguments.

Note that intercepting frequently used methods is a bad idea as it can impact performance.